# Расположить частицы ( hair ) на равном друг от друга расстоянии

Tags: blender, particles

У меня есть кривая плоскость на которую надо расположить полусферы друг от друга на равном расстоянии ( больше 5000 ). Как я могу это реализовать в Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно идеально точно - [плагин Animation Nodes](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/0hbbbc/).

Можно попробовать подразделить поверхность так, чтобы получить нужное количество точек и в настройках частиц выбрать Emit from - Verts.

Можно также подразделить поверхность так, чтобы получить нужное количество полигонов и воспользоваться [инстансингом](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/faces.html),